# Ruby version not update using rbenv on mac

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I follow this tutorial

Install homebrew

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Install Ruby

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile
rbenv install 2.4.0
rbenv global 2.4.0
ruby -v
```

but output ruby -v still

ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]

running on mac OS Sierra 10.12

Comment: What do you get from `rbenv versions`?

Comment: rbenv 1.1.0 I am using iterm2 + terminal

Comment: Have you tried `rbenv rehash`? Also I understand you are using rbenv 1.1.0, but I need the output of `rbenv versions`.

Comment: I already tried rehash noting happen still ruby version 2.0 but I already download 2.4.0. Output is 2.4.0 but ruby version still ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]

Comment: Output of `rbenv local` or `rbenv local 2.4.0`?

Comment: rbenv local = 2.4.0 rbenv global = 2.4.0 but still ruby -v 2.0.0 I cant install rails 5

Answer (score 1):

One of the steps of the installation is this one:

```
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Which writes a command into your `.bash_profile`.

You need to restart your Bash session (quit the Terminal and open a new one) to take it into effect.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issues and mislav's comment here [https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/939][1] fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` line to your `.bash_profile`.

Works for me.